# R readlines encoding issues

Tags: r, encoding

I am trying to read ebook-text in the desired URL:

```
url <- "http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/55/pg55.txt"
raw <- readLines(url, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

However, when I inspect the `raw` object, it return result like this:

```
> raw[1]
[1] "\037‹\b\bÿ†u_\002ÿpg55.txt.utf8.gzip"
> raw[2]
[1] "¾ûçþd‡ú\u008f]»ßð×ÿÝ\177ýïç¶=Æ\bøëÅ\u008fvbñ™\177úGÿÌwg{\177×äÇ¾³cÄEù§XÏo\017íÐØW\177ßM×Ø/ûu,íOm3¬\037óÞþÜ­Ÿlí~î¦õ#?÷ŸfëÁ\037Å2þÜ\035wöÙ\037ûãS{ÕKcõþÐ\u008dëÞn®¿QkØ\016C·Úë\031±€?6»n½ø0L9\001.Ô÷çÃê¼ã'ÿ«o.~ùM³ß÷½mE3.~hp\006Z.Ù?aE?@\022ørÿÔŸ'\u008d\037‹ùaš\032NËä—Ör÷8Ùà\027Ÿ‡V«õÏ±ž\177hº£­Óï\037»cÃc7"
> raw[3]
[1] "W~ –\023\033½ø¦]÷‡väÃþ"
```

How should I read the text properly in this case?

Comment: The data is compressed. You can read it in with `rawdat <- readLines(gzcon(url("http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/55/pg55.txt")))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to using {readr} you can use the `read_file()` function to read the data:

```
library(readr)
url <- "http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/55/pg55.txt"
raw <- read_file(url)
```

This gives a character vector of length 1. You can inspect object `raw`:

```
substr(raw, 1, 50)
[1] "The Project Gutenberg EBook of The Wonderful Wizar"
```